# Pan instead of a skillet

Tags: sauce, frying, salmon, reduction

I'm going to be cooking salmon in a white wine sauce & the directions indicate that I need to use a skillet. I don't have one of these, would I be able to use a normal pan or a frying pan instead of a skillet?

If I do use a non-skillet pan, will that mean I need to take special measures to ensure the same end result; or is the skillet just preferable, but bearing little practical difference for this task?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Try to search in our existing question base to see if someone else already asked your question before posting your question. Check out this possible duplicate: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20198/8305

Comment: ...when is a skillet not a frying pan? I know the difference between a fry pan and a saute pan but I thought "skillet" was a term for the former?

Comment: @Yami most often, when someone says "skillet" they are likely referring to a cast-iron skillet, or some other comparable, heavy-bottomed pan. Typically a fry/saute pan can be inferred to mean just non-stick, or probably some other pan meant to conduct heat more directly than a heavier bottomed one.

Comment: Hi Mary, I think that you can help us help you if you explain the preparation. Bird's answer is all-around good, but but could you describe the method of cooking a bit more? Also, I added some additional queries to make answers appeal more to the root of your question; feel free to roll back if I misinterpreted your post.

Answer (score 2):

A normal frying pan would probably work just fine for you. If you use a non-stick pan you'll tend to get less crisping on whatever you're cooking and if you plan to deglaze to make your sauce you'll get less yummy bits to work with. However, I've used non-stick cookware to make a lot of things (porkchops in white wine sauce, yum!) and it usually turns out fine. Just be aware, too, that if you're using non-stick cookware to fry and your recipe calls for any kind of cooking oil, you should probably use a little less to avoid that gross oil-soaked effect.